# /dev/null permission denied in chroot environment

Tags: apt, permissions, chroot

I have Xubuntu 18.04 in a `chroot` environment. I just dropped it in there from a VM I had of it.

Going into the `chroot` environment, if I try to run `apt update` I get this error:

`/usr/bin/apt-key: 624: /usr/bin/apt-key: cannot create /dev/null: Permission denied`

I have tried most of the solutions here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146633/bash-dev-null-permission-denied 
As well as this solution: https://superuser.com/a/814594 Neither worked. Same exact output.

Is there some way I can get this working? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out the issue. It wasn't readable/writable by all users. Changed it so all users could read and write and it worked. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 5):

I encountered this issue today.

I could resolve it by binding the host machine's /dev/ to chroot environment's /dev/.

```bsh
# Run in host machine as root(sudo)
mount --bind /dev /path/to/chroot/environment/dev
```

Also in my case, I needed to bind 3 more file systems.

```bsh
# Run in host machine as root(sudo)
mount --bind /dev/pts /path/to/chroot/environment/dev/pts
mount --bind /proc /path/to/chroot/environment/proc
mount --bind /sys /path/to/chroot/environment/sys
```

And then chroot into the environment:

```bsh
chroot /path/to/chroot/environment
```

Comment: Is there a reason you would mount --bind /dev and mount --bind /dev/pts? Seems to me mounting /dev would also mount /dev/pts correct?

Comment: @erwin I guess not. I don't have a deep knowledge about it, but it happened to not behave in this way. I needed to explicitly mount /dev/pts/ as this directory didn't exist (or it existed but was empty) after mounting only /dev/

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old and you already found your answer, but another possibility (which I just faced) is that the drive was mounted with the `nodev` option, disabling any character devices such as /dev/null, even though they show up with the proper permission. Just issuing a `mount -o remount,rw /dev/hdaN /mnt` from outside the chroot fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

From `man null`:

```
   These devices are typically created by:

          mknod -m 666 /dev/null c 1 3
          mknod -m 666 /dev/zero c 1 5
          chown root:root /dev/null /dev/zero
```

These commands would have to be executed in the `chroot` environment.

Comment: I tried this and It didn't help. Same exact error.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding GPG keys for an apt repository inside a chroot with `apt-key`, you can also  place them directly into the `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d` directory with a file extension of either `.asc` or `.gpg` according to [this Debian bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=851774) I stumbled across.

In my case, I was trying to add an apt repository inside a `chroot` environment while building a base image for my containers.

For example:

```bsh
wget -q "SOME_URL_HERE" -O- | run_in_chroot sh -c 'cat >/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/mykey.asc';
```

...where `run_in_chroot` runs a command inside a chroot:

```bsh
run_in_chroot() {
    chroot "path/to/directory/to/chroot/into" "$@";
}
```